# Using VLOOKUP to return information based on the maximum value in a range

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use vlookup to return information based on the maximum value of a cell within a range.

I have a table in which each row is a sports team and each column is a weekly points total.

I have 2 cells that show the highest points scored in the current week and the name of the team that scored them.
The team name is generated by the formula 
=VLOOKUP(MAX(Admin!G3:G16),Admin!G3:K16, 5, FALSE)
This works fine.

I also wish to have 2 cells that show the highest weekly points total ever achieved, along with the name of the relevant team.
However, I can not amend the above formula to work on a range instead of a row, and no matter what I do, it always returns an #N/A result for the team name.
The most logical formula I tried is
=VLOOKUP(MAX(Admin!N18:BE31),Admin!N18:BG31, 47, FALSE)

where columns N through BE are the weekly scores (which are generated by a formula, if that makes a difference?) and column BG contains the team names.

Maybe this function isn't designed to work on a range in the same way as a column, maybe I have made an error in the formula, or maybe there is another better way to retrieve the information?

I just can't work it out, so am sincerely hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. 
Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: A small example would be helpful. Hard to know what data you are sifting through otherwise. While you are at that, you may want to research `=index()` and `=match()`, as those two combined are more flexible then `=vlookup()`.

Comment: Why not just add a helper column where each cell holds the maximum score of each team across all weeks? Then you can use a formula like your original one to get the name of the team with the overall maximum.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I can't believe that didn't occur, but it is the perfect and easiest work around. Using the helper column worked a treat and problem now solved, CHEERS.

Thanks also Jacob, I found some interesting examples of Index/Match online that I tried to replicate, but without success. However, I did note a lot of useful features of that function that may well come in handy on this or other projects I am working on, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks Spoonpilot, glad it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the vlookup function works only with columns. So does the match function. You need here to use a formula array (hit "Ctrl + Shift + Enter" once you've typed the function instead of the usual "Enter").

I came to the following function

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$9=$H$2,MATCH($A$2:$A$9,$A$2:$A$9,0),""),1))
```

with :
    1) $A$2:$A$9 = The teams
    2) $B$2:$D$9 = The weekly scores
    3) $H$2 = the maximal score ever achieved

You just need to adapt the ranges and hit "Ctrl + Shift + Enter"

PS: If 2 teams achieved this score, then only the first one will show